# laravel update only reference table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am successfully able to insert using Laravel eloquent one-to-many relationship as you can see the below code.

```
$post = new Post;
$post->title = "my title";
$post->description = "my description";
$post->save();

$comment = new Comment;
$comment->author = "my author";
$comment->comment = "my explain";

$post->comments()->save($comment);
```

How I can UPDATE comments table records ONLY using Laravel eloquent one-to-many relationship?

I have tried the following code to update but it is adding new row in comments
table.

```
$post = Post::find(18);

$comment = new Comment;
$comment->author = "my author";
$comment->comment = "my explain";    

$post->comments()->save($comment);
```

Answer (score 1):

In second code block you are creating new comment. So it add new row in comments table.

If you need to edit some comment, just get it directly from DB and save.

Comment: Well that is easy but I need proper way to update using eloquent one-to-many relationship.

Comment: What concrete functionality with comments you need to implement?

Comment: No concrete functionality I need it but yes I need to implement such logic in other project.

Comment: You can get comments just via `$post->comments()` and change them in `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution after doing some research and debugging.

Solution:

```
$post = Post::find(18);
$comment = array('author'=>'ddd','comment'=>'sss');
$post->comments()->update($comment);
```

Explanation:

We simply need to pass array of columns and we need to use update method.

```
$comment = array('author'=>'ddd','comment'=>'sss');
```

author, comment are columns in comments table.

Post Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

Commend model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

I hope it will help someone.Thanks once again.